# Wordpress site not displaying fonts on Firefox or Chrome - CORS error

Tags: php, wordpress, server, cors, cdn

I have a Wordpress site with a theme installed. I recently updated the theme and Wordpress to their latest versions, and then fonts stopped being rendered in both Chrome and Firefox.

Here is my error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/droidsans/v6/s-BiyweUPV0v-yRb-cjciAzyDMXhdD8sAj6OAJTFsBI.woff2. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
```

I have tried adding the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' to my .htaccess file but I have still not been able to fix the problem.

Domain is [brybell.me/sonomawine](http://brybell.me/sonomawine)

Comment: Are you using HTTPS?

Comment: No, I am not using HTTPS.

Comment: Did you clear your cache? I'm not getting that error at all. It's working fine in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: You are using **Salient** premium theme. It seams, that your problem is related to your theme. So the quickest way to solve your issue is [to open a ticket on the dedicated support forum threads of Salient theme](https://themenectar.ticksy.com/?envato_item_id=4363266) or searching over similar issues within this theme. Themes issues are off-topic in SO.